# executing function in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have some questions regarding this [Code](https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/03_net.py) - neural networks in TensorFlow.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01))


def model(X, w_h, w_o):
    h = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_h)) # this is a basic mlp, think 2 stacked logistic regressions
    return tf.matmul(h, w_o) # note that we dont take the softmax at the end because our cost fn does that for us


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
trX, trY, teX, teY = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 784])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10])

w_h = init_weights([784, 625]) # create symbolic variables
w_o = init_weights([625, 10])

py_x = model(X, w_h, w_o)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=py_x, labels=Y)) # compute costs
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cost) # construct an optimizer
predict_op = tf.argmax(py_x, 1)

# Launch the graph in a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # you need to initialize all variables
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for i in range(100):
        for start, end in zip(range(0, len(trX), 128), range(128, len(trX)+1, 128)):
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end]})
        print(i, np.mean(np.argmax(teY, axis=1) ==
                         sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: teX})))
```

- After a single run of the loop at line 37, how do i call **model()** with **X[0]** and the newly learnt **w_h** and **w_o** , so that I can see the function returns
- Similarly, how to print the values of **h** inside the **model()** function ?

Thanks in advance. I am new to tensorFlow :)

Comment: After each loop at line 37, at line 40 model is being called. X[0] does not make any sense as X is merely a placeholder. teX in line 41 fulfills the purpose of X

Comment: Just to clarify this: 'model is being *used*' is probably more exact since the function `model()` is called only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `feed_dict` translates the placeholders into real value(s). So provide a single entry for `feed_dicts` and evaluate `py_x`.

The following should work:

**For the result (px_y):**

```
print(sess.run(py_x, feed_dict={X: [yoursample]}))
```

**For `h`** it's (almost) the same. But as in the linked code `h` is a private member of `model()` you'll need a reference to `h` in order to evaluate it. The easiest way most probably is to replace lines:

```
(14) return tf.matmul(h, w_o)
with
(14) return (tf.matmul(h, w_o), h)

(26) py_x = model(X, w_h, w_o)
with
(26) py_x, h = model(X, w_h, w_o)
```

and use:

```
print(sess.run(h, feed_dict={X: [yoursample]}))
```

or alternatively (evaluate multiple variables):

```
py_val, h_val = sess.run([py_x, h], feed_dict={X: [yoursample]})
print(py_val, h)
```

**Explanation:**
By the way we told Tensorflow how our Network is constructed we did not need an explicit reference to the (inner/hidden) variable `h`. But in order to evaluate it we do need the reference to define *what exactly* to evaluate.

There are other ways to get the variables out of the guts of Tensorflow, but as we explicitly create this variable a few lines above I'd avoid dropping something into a black box and ask the very same black box later on to give it back.

Comment: thanks. what about the 2nd bullet point ? Should another function be written that just returns _h_ ? Or there a better way to do this ?

Comment: As this question might be interesting for others as well I covered that as well and added some comments.

Comment: thank you, got what i was looking :) Can you suggest some good tutorials for TensorFlow, its a bit tough to understand their documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed it is.. Personally I started trying to understand their tutorials but failed to do so and I so used their final code per tutorial to ping-pong try and understand what they do and their explanations. I like the MNIST examples as images (of written digits) are easier to visualize, reproduce and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question:

- Similarly, how to print the values of h inside the model() function ?

With the function [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print)

```
def model(X, w_h, w_o):
    print_h = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_h)) # this is a basic mlp, think 2 stacked logistic regressions
    h = tf.Print(print_h,[print_h]) # add a node to the execution graph that prints h when ever h is needed and executed in the graph
    return tf.matmul(h, w_o) # note that we dont take the softmax at the end because our cost fn does that for us
```

Good explanation can be found here: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-tf-print-in-tensorflow-aa26e1cff11e