# TensorFlow - Unable to get the value of a variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow. I have two tensors/tensorflow objects, X & Y which basically are two matrices. I perform some computation on them and want to print their value.

```
output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(tf.exp(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), Y))))
print(output.get_shape()) #Shows ()
```

I want to get the value of `output`. I'm unable to print it.

Tried doing this :

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()

output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(tf.exp(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), Y))))

print(output.get_shape())

sess.run(init)
v = sess.run(output)
print(v)
```

But to no avail ! Throws the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype int32 and shape [100]
```

Comment: I explained this procedure just 3 hours ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471921/executing-function-in-tensorflow/42472053?noredirect=1#comment72085226_42472053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message speaks for itself. X and Y  are [placeholders](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder). A placeholder is just an object which is expected to contain a value at runtime. In your present case, you need to do something like following :

`v = sess.run(output, feed_dict = {X : matrix_for_X, Y: matrix_for_Y})`

Comment: Thanks, but this throws the following error :
`TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.`